# encodeABI() throws Uncaught (in promise) Error

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, javascript

I am trying to use encodeABI() on one of my contract methods like this:

```
signTx = async () => {
   ...
   const response = await contract.methods.recoverAddr(fixed_msg_sha, 
   v_decimal, r, s).encodeABI()
   ...
 }
```

Here is the contract implementation of the method:

```
  function recoverAddr(bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public returns (address) {
    address signer = ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s);
    emit LogMyHash(msgHash);
    emit LogMyAddress(signer);
    return signer;
}
```

But what I get is this error:

[image]

However, when I try to use call() or send() on my contract instance, it works just fine. What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you convert your address string to lower case characters?